# Оборот с "благодаря"

Tags: пунктуация

Обособили ли бы вы следующий оборот:

ANDREX VALVE GROUP, благодаря признанию потребителей, сегодня динамично развивается.

Мне кажется, что обособлять не нужно. Тем более:

Конструкции с простыми или составными предлогами благодаря, ввиду, вследствие, по причине, наподобие, подобно, при условии, при наличии, при, вопреки, за неимением, согласно, с согласия, во избежание и др обычно не обособляются, но в художественной речи в зависимости от степени распространенности оборота, его смысловой близости к основной части предложения занимаемого им места по отношению к сказуемому, наличия добавочных 
обстоятельственных значений, стилистических задач и т.п. могут обособляться.

Хотя без запятых тоже как-то не выглядит.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае обособление факультативно, то есть его может и не быть.

"Грамота.ру":  Возможно невыделение оборота, находящегося между подлежащим и сказуемым: *На следующее утро благодаря многочисленным пришельцам в четверть часа остов новой землянки был закончен* (В. Обручев, Земля Санникова).

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/

Answer (score 1):

У предложения не совсем удачная структура, оно плохо читается. Можно предложить два варианта с разными оттенками смысла:

(1) Сегодня ANDREX VALVE GROUP, благодаря признанию потребителей, развивается динамично. Основное сообщение - "развивается динамично".

(2) Сегодня ANDREX VALVE GROUP развивается динамично благодаря признанию потребителей. Основное сообщение - "благодаря признанию потребителей".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Сложно корректировать одно предложение по смыслу, но в любом случае предложение надо перестроить.

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этом предложении как раз нормальная структура. Запятые нужны. А у Софии получилось, что сегодня динамично развивается, а вчера – чёрт его знает. Не развивался или не динамично.